# Grab keyboard key without consuming it in Linux

Tags: linux, keylogger

I`m looking for some method that allows me to grab a keyboard key without send it to linux system.

In other words i`m looking for linux alternative of windows pivoke method SetNextHookEx from user32.dll

Thanks for help

Comment: What is _to grab a keyboard key without send it to linux system_ supposed to mean? How could the system _allow_ you _to grab a_ _key_ if the key has not already been sent _to_ it?

Comment: I understand that you are looking for Linux custom keyboard driver or something like that. You may find answers in [How keyboard's drivers work on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450307/), [The Linux keyboard driver](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1080) and [Creating an input device driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/input/input-programming.html).

Comment: @Armali Maybe i was inaccurate. I ment grab a keybaord key before a char, that is assigned to it, is send to the system.   In Windons this can be done with SetNextHookEx method from user32.dll. I`m looking for linux equivalent of that method

Comment: @U880D Thanks, I`d study this links very carrefully

Comment: I can't find any documentation of _SetNextHookEx_. and I also can't see why it's of importance to you that the key is not sent _to the system_ - after all, how do you imagine to get the key without help of _the system_?

Comment: @Armali, it might be that he means `GetNextHookEx` as in [Get a hook into Windows and use Python to record keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022237/).